# How to send OCO order to binance

Tags: python, api, binance

I would like to ask you for help. I´m trying to change python code from sending limit/market order to OCO order through api to binance. I can make limit order, market order, stop loss limit order. I can´t figure out how to place OCO order...

When I used limit order I was sending order_type=ORDER_TYPE_LIMIT then I used order = client.create_order() and it was working. When I wanted to send market order I used order_type=ORDER_TYPE_MARKET but when I want to make OCO order the only option that I found that should work is:
order = client.create_oco_order() without order_type but here I´m getting error 1013 Stop loss is not supported for this symbol...

I checked https://api.binance.com/api/v1/exchangeInfo

and there is this "orderTypes":["LIMIT","LIMIT_MAKER","MARKET","STOP_LOSS_LIMIT","TAKE_PROFIT_LIMIT"],"icebergAllowed":true,"ocoAllowed":true,

So I can´t use order_type. There is not ORDER_TYPE_OCO and ocoAllowed is true so I should be able to send oco order. But I´m getting "error 1013: Stop loss orders are not supported for this symbol. order failed".

What I want is to set "price" as limit sell order to take profit highier when price will get there and to set stop loss "stopPrice" lower if price will go down...at once. This is how OCO should works.

Can somebody please give me an advice how to do it? I´m not python guru I´m just changing one code that I found and what I understand is if oco is allowed stop loss should be allowed too. Thanks

Comment: I finally found the answer on github. To place oco order there are required another parameters. To create an OCO order, the following parameters are required:
symbol
quantity
side
price
stopPrice
stopLimitPrice
stopLimitTimeInForce. I added stopLimitPrice and stopLimitTimeInForce and it is working now. OCO order requires 3 different prices I had only 2. https://github.com/ccxt/ccxt/issues/5966

Answer (score 11):

so that all interested have a precise answer about the solution of this problem, I include the code with the comments.

I'll use an **OCO sell order** as an example in BTCUSDT.

Imagine I have 1 BTC. The current price is at 30157.85 and I want to sell 1 BTC much higher at 32000.07

But the price does not rise and begins to fall, so I place my stopPrice at 29283.03 where the limit sell order will be opened at the price 29000.00

This means that I will sell at 32000.07 or 29000.00 USDT. The order is written as follows:

```
order= client.order_oco_sell(
    symbol= 'BTCUSDT',                                            
    quantity= 1.00000,                                            
    price= '32000.07',                                            
    stopPrice= '29283.03',                                            
    stopLimitPrice= '29000.00',                                            
    stopLimitTimeInForce= 'FOK')
```

Note that the OCO order requires the stopLimitTimeInForce parameter. I have used the value 'FOK' but I leave you here the description of the different values that you can use: https://help.bybit.com/hc/en-us/articles/360039749233-What-are-time-in-force-TIF-GTC-IOC-FOK-

Note well that the price, stopPrice, stopLimitPrice and stopLimitTimeInForce parameters are strings and not float or decimal.

Comment: The question is for Binance, but this answer references ByBit documentation, is it applicable to Binance as well?

Comment: Yes @Jason. It is the procedure that I myself use for Binance. I don't trade on Bybit. The stopLimitTimeInForce values refer to concepts that are valid on any platform.

Comment: The problem of the OCO order is that there is limit order instead of market order, I stopped using it because it just skipped my limit orders and price went down... It is not guaranteed that limit order will be filled so it is usefull to me without market sell order, bots always skip your limit sell orders if price is going down...

Comment: @Garik, it seems Binance just update their docs about OCO: https://academy.binance.com/en/articles/what-is-an-oco-order

Comment: Referring to "Note that the OCO order requires the stopLimitTimeInForce parameter". This is because the documentation of the wrapper says: "stopLimitPrice (str) – If provided, stopLimitTimeInForce is required." I would have preferred Binance to allow to skip this stopLimitPrice, and have just the sell limit price, but for some reasons OCO does not work without stop limit. Source: https://python-binance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/binance.html?highlight=client.order_oco_sell#binance.client.Client.order_oco_sell

Comment: Continued: of course, the wrapper is made after API. My point is that OCO saves some workload on the user side who otherwise would had to put two orders: 1) a stop loss limit order (to sell on loss if the case arises) and 2) another sell limit order on take profit level, but the second not possible because the assets are used for no. 1). So, this means to have a loop on user side and monitor price when going at Take Profit level.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a code snippet that simulates OCO TP/SL orders. Tested with CCXT 2023.1 and Binance in 2023.02.

Comments are inline. As a side note, for SL instead of STOP_MARKET you can use STOP, which is nothing else than a LIMIT order with a trigger price.  So, additionally to the trigger price you'd need to specify the price for the LIMIT order price as well. The disadvantage of this order is that there's a risk of it to be never executed since it places a LIMIT order after the triggering event, and depending on Binance execution speed and OrderBook it can remain in the OB if the Market will go further in the wrong direction.

Thus, to be safe - for SL I'd recommend the use only STOP_MARKET.

```py
# Create market SELL order
market_buy_order = binance.create_market_order(symbol, side='sell', amount=amount, params={'reduceOnly': False})

# Create SL/TP orders with reduceOnly. Note: TP order is a LIMIT order, that would benefit of the Taker fees (which on Binance are hlaf of the Maker)
sl_order = binance.create_order(symbol, "STOP_MARKET", 'buy', amount=amount, params={"stopPrice": stop_loss_price, 'reduceOnly': True, 'timeInForce': 'GTC'})
tp_order = binance.create_limit_order(symbol, side='buy', amount=amount, price=take_profit_price, params={'reduceOnly': True, 'timeInForce': 'GTC'})

# And close all the orders.
# Note - if in the meantime the position will be closed by the one of the SL/TPorders, this Market order won't affect our positions as it's reduceOnly.
market_close_order = binance.create_market_order(symbol, side='buy', amount=amount, params={'reduceOnly': True})

try:
    binance.cancel_order(id=sl_order['id'], symbol=symbol)
except ccxt.base.errors.OrderNotFound:
    print('Order not found')

# Note: the TP order, will be canceled automatically by Binance after the position is closed by Market order. I'm not sure why this happens, but it does, so we cancel the TPorder just for an extra safety.
try:
    binance.cancel_order(id=tp_order['id'], symbol=symbol)
except ccxt.base.errors.OrderNotFound:
    print('Order not found')
```